# Spring 5 и UTF-8

Tags: java, spring, utf-8

Пользуюсь `Spring 5`.
Полезли проблемы с `UTF-8`. Шлёт такое:

> ÐÐµÑ ÑÐ°ÐºÐ¾Ð³Ð¾ Ð±ÑÐµÐ½Ð´Ð°: 1000. ÐÐ¾Ð¶Ð°Ð»ÑÐ¹ÑÑÐ°,
>   Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ð²ÐµÑÑÑÐµ Ð·Ð°Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ñ.

В `Spring 5` немного иначе устроена инициализация, наследоваться приходится от других классов. Пока так:

```
@Configuration
public class AppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        addEncodingFilter(servletContext);
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

...

private void addEncodingFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes
                = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding
                = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
        characterEncoding.setAsyncSupported(true);
    }
}
```

Взял UTF-фильтр из реализации `Spring 4`. В метод заходит. Не работает.

Есть ли у кого-то готовое решение, как задать кодировку и решить проблему?

P.S. Прописал настройки UTF-8 следующим образом:

```
@Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[] {characterEncodingFilter};
    }
```

Когда маршрут проходит через контроллер и возвращается ResponseEntity, проблемы нет — данные на кириллице, взятые из БД, отображаются нормально (впрочем, они отображались нормально и до этого).

Проблема в тех сообщениях, которые выбрасываются при помощи исключений, шаблоны для которых берутся в `"/i18n"`.

Когда, допустим, в контроллер приходит несуществующий id, которого нет в БД, это проверяется на входе в сервис и если такого значения нет, выбрасывается исключение, которое отправляет сообщение (пример такого сообщения Вы видите выше). В противном случае, придёт просто нулловый DTO и клиент не поймёт, что не так. Именно эти сообщения приходят в плохой кодировке.

Может быть, необходимы какие-то настройки проперти-файлов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в не заданной кодировке сообщений, которая должна быть указана в WebConfig:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("i18n/messages");
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return source;
}
```